# Windows not booting after restoring Ubuntu 11.04 bootloader

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04

I was having a multiboot setup with Windows 7 Home Premium and Ubuntu 11.04. I upgraded Windows to Windows 7 Ultimate. To restore the boot loader, I used something like the following command from terminal of Ubuntu live CD.

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/media/0d104aff-ec8c-44c8-b811-92b993823444/boot /dev/sda
```

Now I can boot into Ubuntu. But when I try to select Windows 7, it is throwing an error that `/dev/sda2` cannot be found.

How can I make Windows 7 boot from grub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your partition layout probably changed such that Windows is no longer on the `/dev/sda2` partition.  Try running this command under Ubuntu that will scan your drives and build a new GRUB configuration:

```
sudo update-grub
```